# C++ based DSL that supports use of operator[] with list of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I need to write a custom DSL in C++ that will be used to define Pokémon, abilities, teaching abilities to a specific Pokémon and then simulating the duel. So far, I've managed to make most of the DSL work as it was described, but I am having a hard time implementing the following code:

```
DEAR "Pikachu" LEARN [
    ABILITY_NAME(Electric_Shock)
    ABILITY_NAME(Lightning_Rod)
]
```

This DSL code should basically translate into valid C++ code that teaches the specified abilities to the Pokémon specified after the DEAR macro. What I have done so far for this specific part is the following:

```
/**
 * \brief 
 */
#define DEAR ; (*getPokemonByName(
/**
 * \brief 
 */
#define LEARN ))

/**
 * \brief Retrieves the ability with the given name, if it exists.
 * Otherwise, nullptr is returned.
 * \param name The name of the ability to look for.
 */
#define ABILITY_NAME(name) getAbilityByName(#name)
```

The `getPokemonByName()` returns a `Pokemon*` if a Pokémon with the given name (following the DEAR macro) exists, or `nullptr` otherwise (I will emit an error and terminate before accessing the `nullptr` later). The same logic applies to the `getAbilityByName()` function, which in turn returns a `SingleAbilityExpr*`.

My thought process is to figure out a way to combine the various `SingleAbilityExpr*`s within the `[]` into one, and then overload the `operator[]` in the Pokémon class in order to teach the abilities to the selected Pokémon. The issue is that I cannot figure out a way to hack this functionality with this specific syntax. Is there an alternative to my approach that can achieve what I want?

Initially, I was hoping that if the `ABILITY_NAME` macro was to emit a `,` at the end, I could overload the `operator,` in the `SingleAbilityExpr` class and thus collect them this way. Sadly, this does not seem to work due to the last trailing comma, which I have found no way of consuming using c++11.

Comment: How fixed are you on operator `[]`? Using `{}` instead, you could turn this into an initializer list instead. In any case, the very approach is bad for many reasons. Consider submitting this to codereview.stackexchange.com after you got it running to get a full review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach is to make `getAbilityByName` return a collection with overload `operator () (Collection &) -> Collection &` and define macro as

`#define ABILITY_NAME(mp_name) (getAbilityByName(#mp_name))`

So the list will expand to something like

```
[
    (getAbilityByName("Electric_Shock")) // () are normal parentheses
    (getAbilityByName("Lightning_Rod")) // () are overloaded operator
]
```

Not only this requires just one overloaded operator, but you also get a proper order of evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

C++23 adds multi-argument `operator[]`, but it's useless in your case, because you'll end up with following: (after adding a comma to `ABILITY_NAME`)

```
foo[
    getAbilityByName("a"),
    getAbilityByName("b"),
    getAbilityByName("c"), // <--
]
```

Which is of no use, becaues the trailing comma is an error.

Instead you should do `#define ABILITY_NAME(name) +getAbilityByName(#name)`, where `getAbilityByName()` returns a list of abilities (a wrapper around `std::vector` probably), with overloaded operators:

- Unary `+`, which returns the list unchanged, and
- Binary `+`, which concatenates the lists.

Then `operator[]` should accept the list as the only argument:

```
foo[
    +getAbilityByName("a") // Unary +
    + getAbilityByName("b") // Binary +
    + getAbilityByName("c") // Binary +
]
```

Comment: That's excellent, thank you so much for the idea. I had thought about the binary operator approach but was completely missing the unary overload. This work perfectly!